# QGIS - PYQGIS Import gpx as vector layer

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, vector, gpx

I'm trying to use the python console to import some gpx files as vector layers.
When I do it manually I have to choose which layers to add, my options are:

[image: Select vector layers to add image]

I've tried various versions of the code from the manual:

```
uri = "path/to/gpx/file.gpx?type=track"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer name you like", "gpx")
```

I also tried adding the layer name I want like:

```
path/to/gpx/file.gpx|layername=track_points?type=track", "layer name you like", "gpx")
```

Edit:
On each try I don't get any errors, it just doesn't import anything, ie no new layers in the layers panel. I would like to import the files using python as I have quite a large number of them. I could do it manually but I would have to choose the track_points layer for each file

Edit:
From Joseph's answer I adapted his code and got what I wanted, not entirely sure how but if it helps anyone else:

```
import os
path = 'Path/To/GPX Files/'
names = ["track_points"]
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
    layername = f[:-4]
        for name in names: 
            iface.addVectorLayer(os.path.join(dirpath, f)+"?type="+name, layername, "gpx")
```

Comment: When you have loaded the layers manually, save each of them as layer file. Use a file editor to inspect the layer file and look for the uri string. This is the string you have to pass from pyqgis to load one out of several layers from such multi layer datasources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only **half an answer** as the following code can be used to import `waypoints`, `routes` and `tracks` but not `route_points` or `track_points` (these seem to be replaced by the `tracks` layer).

```
import os

path = "path/to/gpx/folder"
names = ["waypoint", "route", "track", "route_point", "track_point"]

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        for name in names:
            iface.addVectorLayer(os.path.join(dirpath, f)+"?type="+name, name, "gpx")
```

Not sure how to import the last two layers using PyQGIS. The code was adapted from this useful post:

- [iface.addVectorLayer on a gml file causes “Select vector layers to add” dialog (pyqgis)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178509/iface-addvectorlayer-on-a-gml-file-causes-select-vector-layers-to-add-dialog).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to retreive all layers of a GPX with PyQGIS by doing:

```py
import os

path = "path/to/gpx/folder"
names = ["waypoints", "routes", "tracks", "route_points", "track_points"]

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        for name in names:
            iface.addVectorLayer(os.path.join(dirpath, f)+"|layername="+name, name, "ogr")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the correct solution is Jean-François Bourdon solution, because you can select witch layer you want (It's what where are seeing in the picture of this Question).

I was trying to convert a GPX Track file in points, not in a line.

If I use `"?type="` [Wapoint, track or route] Qgis import track like a line.

But if I use `"|layername="` I can select 'track_points', and then I have a GPX file conversion in points.

When I read the first time Jean-François Bourdon solution, I don't see this important difference.