# Adding all the layers in a KML file in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, kml

I've a KML file that contains several layers, if I use the usual method of adding vector layers from a file it only adds the first layer (the Point layer)

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Test.kml", "Test", "ogr")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

How to add all the layers in this file?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To load a **single kml**:

```
fileName = "C:\Users\fran\Downloads\kml\KML_Samples.kml"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(fileName,"test","ogr")
subLayers =layer.dataProvider().subLayers()

for subLayer in subLayers:
    name = subLayer.split('!!::!!')[1]
    uri = "%s|layername=%s" % (fileName, name,)
    #Create layer
    sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'ogr')
    #Add layer to map
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

To load a **folder with kml**:

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\fran\Downloads\kml'
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.kml' in file:
            fileName = os.path.join(r, file)
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(fileName,"test","ogr")
            subLayers =layer.dataProvider().subLayers()

            for subLayer in subLayers:
                name = subLayer.split('!!::!!')[1]
                uri = "%s|layername=%s" % (fileName, name,)
                #Create layer
                sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'ogr')
                #Add layer to map
                QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
```

**Tested on QGIS 3.6**

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same steps explained in this question about GML .gz files and it worked.

[iface.addVectorLayer on a gml file causes "Select vector layers to add" dialog (pyqgis)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178509/iface-addvectorlayer-on-a-gml-file-causes-select-vector-layers-to-add-dialog)

1- Open one of the layers

2- Get its full URL iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()

3- Iterate through them

Comment: I know this post is from several months ago, but could you (or someone)  expand on this solution please?
I looked at the link but that's not clear either. They don't explain what exactly they are editing.
1 - open the layer how?
3- what do you mean by iterate through them?

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/322960/49538