# Add a QGIS vectorlayer by geometry type

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gml

I wanted to add a GML layer to my QGIS file, but filtered by geometry type. (the file has multiple geometry types in it, with the same layer name, and same layerID.

I came across this post: [iface.addVectorLayer on a gml file causes "Select vector layers to add" dialog (pyqgis)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178509/iface-addvectorlayer-on-a-gml-file-causes-select-vector-layers-to-add-dialog).

Here they filter it by `"|layername="+name`

But how can I filter it by geometry type?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter it by `"|geometrytype=Point"` or `"|geometrytype=CurvePolygon"` or `"|geometrytype=LineString"`

It will look something like this:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(file_open + "|geometrytype=Point", "vlayer_name", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```